# clojure: reverse with sort and without it

Tags: clojure

**reverse** is not working as it supposed to

```
user=> (reverse (list 5 7 9 0))
(0 9 7 5)
```

Shouldn't it return

```
(9 7 5 0)
```

However reverse works fine with sort

```
user=> (reverse (sort (list 5 7 9 0)))
(9 7 5 0)
```

Can anybody explain the behavior of first case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's what [`reverse`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reverse) is supposed to do:

> Returns a seq of the items in coll in reverse order. Not lazy.

It's *reverse order*, not *reverse **sorted** order*.